# Selecting item number in JSON from Facebook Graph API

Tags: jquery, html, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a web app that uses the Facebook Graph API which displays all of your profile pictures on one page in a big collage.

I'm using the following code to consume the API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #images { padding:0; margin:0; overflow: hidden;}
  #images img { width:200px; height:200px; border:none;}
  #lists li { display: table;}
  #lists img { width:200px; height: 200px; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="profile"></div> 

<script>

var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/733380053/photos?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBALj91OSuexVZBpZBVH6d4V8VPJtZAKJmm0YzWWUvHe22hxEXZA6MRDqgAwPyCUlqJTufsVbcc2xUw2bEgqQaW3tePkew1QZDZD"

$.getJSON(fburl, function(data){

     var img = data["picture"];
     $("#profile").append("<h3>"+ img +"</h3>");

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, i want to be able to just get the picture source of each picture and append it in

an HTML img src tag, from the following example:

```
data: [{id:10150556838025864, from:{name:, id:693815863}, tags:{,…},…},…]
0: {id:10150556838025864, from:{name:, id:693815863}, tags:{,…},…}
created_time: "2011-12-22T00:31:40+0000"
from: {name:, id:693815863}
height: 540
icon: "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif"
id: "10150556838025864"
images: [{height:540, width:720,…}, {height:135, width:180,…}, {height:97, width:130,…},…]
link: "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=10920894&id=693815863"
picture: "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/394974_10150556838025864_693815863_10920894_526292479_s.jpg"
position: 34
source: "http://a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/394974_10150556838025864_693815863_10920894_526292479_n.jpg"
tags: {,…}
updated_time: "2011-12-22T00:31:45+0000"
width: 720
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/733380053/photos?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBALj91OSuexVZBpZBVH6d4V8VPJtZAKJmm0YzWWUvHe22hxEXZA6MRDqgAwPyCUlqJTufsVbcc2xUw2bEgqQaW3tePkew1QZDZD"

$.getJSON(fburl, function(data){
    //var data = data["data"][0]["picture"];
    $.each(data["data"], function() {
        $a = $("<a></a>").attr("href", this.link);
        $img = $("<img />").attr("src", this.picture);
        $a.append($img)
        $("#profile").append($a);
    });
});
```

**UPDATED**

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qbpAZ/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry it didn't seem to work. I don't even get an error, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realise your method of accessing `data` was incorrect. I've updated my answer.

Comment: as an addition to this, how would you turn those images into links that go back to the original facebook page for the image.

Comment: @LordSnoutimus I've updated again - I assumed the `link` property in the Facebook feed is the link to the image, it may be incorrect, but you should be able to amend it as needed to fix that.