# How to Fetch Facebook Photos from Albums using Jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, photo

Can anyone help me? I am trying to pull all of the photos from Facebook Albums

this previous answer is close but I need to pull **all photos within albums** not just the profile photos:

[Selecting item number in JSON from Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834205/selecting-item-number-in-json-from-facebook-graph-api)

OK, here is my script:

```
<script>

 var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/artisticpassion/albums?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAE6xJxnAdD383u6h5CAjHmTbZCnoccvtS4AwDgL2SEP9wl92635df3KcV0T0ZB2ZAAZCmhEu7ZAuM2g7w8FM0XzqAnfZBMzgZDZD"

    $.getJSON(fburl, function(data){
    //var data = data["data"][0]["picture"];
    $.each(data["data"], function() {
        $a = $("<a></a>").attr("href", this.link);
        $img = $("<img />").attr("src", this.picture);
        $a.append($img)
        $("#photos").append($a);
    });
});

</script>
```

The photos are then attached to a div, as follows:

```
<div id="photos"></div>
```

Thanks a lot for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:   replace "albums" with "photos"

```
 var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/artisticpassion/photos?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAE6xJxnAdD383u6h5CAjHmTbZCnoccvtS4AwDgL2SEP9wl92635df3KcV0T0ZB2ZAAZCmhEu7ZAuM2g7w8FM0XzqAnfZBMzgZDZD"

    $.getJSON(fburl, function(data){
    //var data = data["data"][0]["picture"];
    $.each(data["data"], function() {
        $a = $("<a></a>").attr("href", this.link);
        $img = $("<img />").attr("src", this.picture);
        $a.append($img)
        $("#photos").append($a);
    });
});
```